# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' ocr

Tags: python, ocr, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests
import io
import json
import os

cur_path=os.getcwd()
img_name = input("input file name : ")
image_path = os.path.join(cur_path, img_name)
img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

sample = img

# Ocr
url_api = "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image"
_, compressedimage = cv2.imencode(".jpg", sample, [1, 90])
file_bytes = io.BytesIO(compressedimage)

result = requests.post(url_api,
              files = {"screenshot.jpg": file_bytes},
              data = {"apikey": "helloworld",
                      "language": "eng"})

result = result.content.decode()
result = json.loads(result)

parsed_results = result.get("ParsedResults")[0]
text_detected = parsed_results.get("ParsedText")
print(text_detected)


cv2.imshow("Img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It's all about the code.

An error occurred while trying to change the image to text with OCR. It's embarrassing that it didn't work out of the blue. I need your help...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programming/OCR_PY/venv/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    parsed_results = result.get("ParsedResults")[0]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

It's all about the error.

Comment: You need to look at `result` with `print(result)` before proceeding

Comment: Looks like `result` is a string and you can't call the `get()` function on it.

Comment: Have these comments been helpful in resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

api key has been expired get a free new one by registering in the website ocr.space but number of calls is limited to 500 per day per ip